# Where can I find a reference of Data Types accepted by control property in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Is there any reference available that lists the Data Types accepted by the control's property in wpf? For example, TextBox's Text property accepts string.

In particular, I want to know what Data Type does the Button's Command property accepts. I know it can accept RelayCommands but I don't know what other Data Type (or object type) did it accept.

Comment: how do you come to knowTextBox's Text property accepts string ? Same way you can see for other properties.

Comment: It's accepting everything inheriting from `ICommand` I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put you keyboard cursor on that property and press F1 to get to the online or offline help.

There you will find everything about that property.

By the way: RelayCommand does not belong to the default .NET libraries. You need any class which implements the ICommand interface.

Update (as desired: more precisely):

Create a button in XAML, add a `Command` attribute and press F1 on it. The help should open on `ButtonBase.Command` Property page. Here you can find in the 'Syntax' section the signature of the property: `public ICommand Command { get; set; }`. So you see: the type of the `Command` property is `ICommand`. – Fratyx 22 hours ago

By the way: another possibility is pressing F12 ("Go to Definition"). Depending on where the source code is from, it will open the source code, pseudo code from metadata or the object browser.

Comment: Your answer really helped me, now I know how to obtain details about specific object. But how did you know that it accepts any class that implements the ICommand interface? I didn't find it by doing what you have said. Is there any reference that documents it?

Comment: Create a button in XAML, add a `Command` attribute and press F1 on it. The help should open on `ButtonBase.Command Property` page. Here you can find in the `Syntax` section the signature of the property: `public ICommand Command { get; set; }`. So you see: the type of the `Command` property is `ICommand`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Please incorporate your comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Command   : Gets or sets the command to invoke when this button is
>   pressed. (Inherited from ButtonBase.)

Hence it just points to a command which will be invoked when the button is clicked. It doesn’t accept any other data.

**EDIT :**
Adding more info as per asker's questions.

The Command should be set to an `ICommand` property in the view model and this `ICommand` will be invoked when you click on the button. Also the button state can be controlled using this `Command` property of button.

**A command is something which you can invoke during a particular event occurs**. This command can be handled in the view model to execute some particular action when the button is clicked.

To know what data type each property takes, you can refer the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com) documentation corresponding to each control. See the link I already referred above for Button class.

Comment: `It doesn’t accept any other data`  - I've just used the word _data_ because I don't know what to call it. What I know is that it accepts _something_ . My question is how could I know what to _pass_ to that property? As what you have said, it gets or sets the `command` to invoke ... . Now, what is the definition of `command` ? How could I know that an object is a `command` ? Is there any reference that lists all the objects that I can _pass_ to a specific property? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer really helps me but I will accept Fratyx's answer for showing **how** to obtain the information I need. Anyway, I will vote up your answer when I have enough reps.

Comment: It's ok. Nobody is here to get reputation. Happy to share knowledge with others. :) Glad that you got the point behind `Command`.

Comment: I know that. But voting up and accepting an answer is a pointer for others for them to know what answer/s is worth reading. And in this case, your answer is. Sometimes, in my experience, I learn from the unaccepted answer. It's a case to case basis anyway so your answer deserves an up-vote.

Comment: Either way I don't mind. The same thing I too meant. Thanks anyway.